# How to reassign "legal" permission in iTunesConnect

Tags: app-store, app-store-connect, apple-id

On our first iOS app, the person who started up our account with Apple assigned the "legal" permission to our shared support mail, and as such, the "legal" permission was assigned to that Apple ID.  Even though the CEO filled in all the paperwork there, having access to that mail as well, "legal" should not have been assigned to that AppleID.

We need to now move that permission from the shared support mail over to our CEO's own company mail, but I can't seem to move that permission over, even while logged in as the current "legal" user.  The check box for "legal" seems to be unclickable.

Is there any way to CHANGE the AppleID that is assigned to "legal?"

Answer (score 9, accepted):

See instructions for Transferring the Team Agent Role (legal role) on this page: 
https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/IDEs/Conceptual/AppDistributionGuide/ManagingYourTeam/ManagingYourTeam.html

In a nutshell (from the page above):

> Sign in to developer.apple.com/account as the team agent, and click
>   Membership.
>
> Scroll down to Settings, and click Transfer Team Agent Role.
>
> Follow the instructions that appear in a series of dialogs.
>
> For example, you will be asked to choose a new team agent and sign an
>   Agent Transferor Agreement.

Comment: I can't see "Transfer Team Agent Role" in the "Membership" section.

Answer (score 2):

The legal role can only be reassigned by contacting the developer support
https://developer.apple.com/contact/submit/

Comment: This is not correct. The steps in Will Swan's answer work fine.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly and you would like to sign the legal role to another person, you have o do that under the **User and Roles** Tab in iTunes Connect. To change the user's roles you need to have the admin account. If you want to change the Apple ID that is used to sign all the contacts, that is unfortunately not possible. This is in most cases the initial email with which the account was initially created. This unfortunately will have to stay the same unless you convert from a private to a company account. Hope that helps.

Comment: I have a company account and I would like to change the legal account. How can I proceed? Following the Will Swan instructions I can't find the "Transfer Team Agent Role" button. From the User and Roles Tab I'm not able to change the legal account.